# React - Drag'n'Drop Image upload into DraftJS Wysiwyg

Tags: reactjs, draftjs, react-draft-wysiwyg

I have implemented DraftJS Wysiwyg HTML Editor into my form, including the Drag n Drop plugin and it works good. See below for current implementation.

What I want to achieve is that I want to trigger the image upload by dropping the image into the whole editor, not just into the *'Drop the file or click to upload'* window

How to edit the solution to achieve this?

[Current solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6taS.png)

jsx

```
const [editorState, setEditorState] = React.useState(
  EditorState.createEmpty()
);

const onEditorStateChange = (newState) => {
  setEditorState(newState);
  const htmlValue = draftToHtml(
    convertToRaw(editorState.getCurrentContent())
  );
  setInputs({ id: props.id, value: htmlValue });
};

const uploadImageCallBack = (file) => {
  const imageObject = {
    file: file,
    localSrc: URL.createObjectURL(file),
  };
  addImage(imageObject);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve({ data: { link: imageObject.localSrc } });
  });
};

...      
<Editor
  editorState={editorState}
  onEditorStateChange={onEditorStateChange}
  readOnly={props.disabled}
  plugins={[dndFileUploadPlugin]}
  toolbar={{
    image: {
      uploadCallback: uploadImageCallBack,
      previewImage: true,
      alt: { present: true, mandatory: false },
      inputAccept: "image/gif,image/jpeg,image/jpg,image/png,image/svg",
    },
  }}
/>
```

I havent found any resources which could help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `onDrop` function of the `Editor`.

Handle that drop event and pass the image to your `uploadImageCallBack` function:

```js
const handleEditorDrop = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (e.dataTransfer.files.length > 0) {
    const file = e.dataTransfer.files[0];
    if (file.type.startsWith("image")) {
      uploadImageCallBack(file);
    }
  }
};
```

```
<Editor
  ...
  onDrop={handleEditorDrop}
  ...
/>
```

Comment: This works great, unfortunately, it does not add images to the HTML. Gotta figure that one too. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figured out like this

```js
import { AtomicBlockUtils } from 'draft-js';

export const loadImage = (file: File) =>
    new Promise((resolve) => {
        const image = new Image();
        image.onload = () => {
            const height = image.height;
            const width = image.width;
            resolve({ src: image.src, width, height });
        };
        image.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
});
const uploadImageCallBack = async (file) => {
  const img: any = await loadImage(file);
  const imageObject = {
    file: file,
    localSrc: img.src,
  };
  addImage(imageObject);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve({ data: { link: imageObject.localSrc, metadata: img } });
  });
};
const handleEditorDrop = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
    if (e.dataTransfer.files.length > 0) {
      const file = e.dataTransfer.files[0];
        if (file.type.startsWith('image')) {
          const newFile: any = await uploadImageCallBack(file);
          const entityData = { src: newFile.data.link, height: newFile.data?.metadata?.height || '320px', width: newFile.data?.metadata?.width || '320px' };
          const entityKey = editorState.getCurrentContent().createEntity('IMAGE', 'MUTABLE', entityData).getLastCreatedEntityKey();
          const newEditorState = AtomicBlockUtils.insertAtomicBlock(editorState, entityKey, ' ');
          setEditorState(newEditorState);
        }
      } 
    };
<div onDrop={handleEditorDrop}>
  <Editor.../>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, quick question - does the image show in the comments or the textarea of the tool? I"m assuming your api returns a response in which you can insert it into it?